# Ruby sort based on predefined list

Tags: ruby, sorting

I have an array of `objects`. Each object has an attribute we'll call `display_name`.

I want to sort this array based on a predefined list of values.

So if the predefined list looks something like this `["Ball", "Cat", "Helicopter", "France"]`

Then the objects with the display_name attribute matching `"Ball"` with be at the head of the list, those with `"Cat"` second in the list and so on and so forth.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can use [Enumerable#sort_by](http://ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Enumerable.html#method-i-sort_by):

```
list = ["Ball", "Cat", "Helicopter", "France"] 
elements = [{:display_name => 'Cat'}, {:display_name => 'Unknown'}, {:display_name => 'Ball'}]

# sort by index in the list. If not found - put as last.
elements.sort_by { |e| list.index(e[:display_name]) || list.length } 
# => [{:display_name=>"Ball"}, {:display_name=>"Cat"}, {:display_name=>"Unknown"}]
```

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to do something like:

```
require 'ostruct'

list = %w{Ball Cat Helicopter France}
items = [
  OpenStruct.new(:display_name => 'Helicopter'),
  OpenStruct.new(:display_name => 'France'),
  OpenStruct.new(:display_name => 'Ball'),
  OpenStruct.new(:display_name => 'Cat'),
]

items.sort { |x,y| list.index(x.display_name) <=> list.index(y.display_name) }
```

Note, this isn't deterministic if you have multiple items with the same display name.